# Android Studio で Logcat の行数の変更

Tags: android-studio

Eclipseの時にはLogcatの行数を変更する事ができましたが、Android Studioでは該当の箇所を見つけられません。

ある一定量に達すると古いものから削除されるので、何かしら行数を変更するものがいると思っています。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://germanogiudici.wordpress.com/2008/12/17/increase-console-output-size-in-intellij-idea-8/ より。
AndroidStudioの実行媒体のあるフォルダのidea.propertiesという設定ファイルがあり、
その中のidea.cycle.buffer.sizeの値を変更することで保持できるログの行数が増えるようです。

Comment: おーありました、idea.cycle.buffer.size=1024　ってなってました。
すごく助かりましたこれでログ収集が楽になると思います。